# JComboBox only appears where window was created

Tags: jcombobox

I have a very large database program that I am developing in IntelliJ IDEA, I am using the GridLayoutManager from IntelliJ and just became aware of a bug with my JComboBoxes, when I click on them they appear where the window was initially shown; If I move the window the combo box list stays in place if its not showing, else if it is showing it moves with the window, any ideas would be much appreciated

- OSX 10.9
- Java 8
- IntelliJ Idea 16

This is the source for the dialog, IntelliJ handles creation of components 
behind the scenes...

```
public DestinationSetupDialog(){
    super(ResourceLoader.TITLE);

    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

    closeButton.addActionListener(e -> dispose());
    saveButton.addActionListener(e -> saveData());

    selectStartDate.setModel(Dates.populateDates(365).getModel());
}

private void saveData(){

}
```

Is this an issue with setting the model ? Because even newly created empty JComboBoxes do the same thing.